# Get JSON response containing Github user list using AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, json, github, android-async-http, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to get response with user json list from github api.

Could anyone tell me the reason why code execution path doesn't reach overriden methods **onFailure()** and **onSuccess**?

```
public String getResponse()
{
    AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
    params.put("since","0");
    client.get("https://api.github.com/users", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                                      Throwable arg3) {
                    userList.clear();
                    userList.addFirst("Items didn't load properly");

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

                    try {
                        content = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
                        //content is json response that can be parsed.
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        userList.clear();
                        userList.add("Some encoding problems occured");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    return content;
}
```

These methods just ignored for some reason. After **client.get(...)** it jumps right to **return content**.

Any ideas about the reason of it? What am I doing wrong?

Would appreciate any advice.

---

**EDIT:**
SO the proper way is to do that is to operate with response within the **onSuccess(...)** method?

```
                    @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {

                    try {
                        content = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
                        //content is json response that can be parsed.

                        parseResponseAmount(content, 10); //operate with response 
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        userList.clear();
                        userList.add("Some encoding problems occured");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

And I try to parse information from response like:

```
private  void parseResponseAmount (String response, int amount)
{
    try {
        JSONArray readerArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            JSONObject userObject = (JSONObject) readerArray.get(i);
            String login = userObject.getString("login");
            getUserList().add(login);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        getUserList().clear();
        getUserList().add("Failed to parse response");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but that code still doesn't work. In event-driven development it caused by mouse move, key presses etc. What causes these **onSuccess()** and **onFailure()** to occur? What is the precondition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using AsyncHttpClient. Do you know what "***Async***" means?

It is a shortening of "***Asynchronous***", which means "occurring independently of the main program flow". Your main program thread will not wait for the AsyncHttpClient to complete its request before continuing. That's why your `getResponse()` method return immediately.

You should design your app to operate on **event-driven programming** principles; this means, in your case, that you would spawn whatever process or method you need to handle the response from the `onSuccess()` interface method.

So, you probably won't be returning anything from `getResponse()`. You can make it `void`. The `AsyncHttpResponseHandler()` you're instantiating and passing to the `get()` method is an interface which the library will call when certain events take place—that is, when the *GET* request succeeds or fails.

Finally, you will have to show your data somehow. I'm assuming it is in a ListView? If so, you will need to notify the ListView that its data has changed (or possibly recreate the adapter with new data). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example). Also, I'm not sure but you may have to use `runOnUIThread()` to update your views, since this is running on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for answer! That what happens when you work with new libraries without reading its documentation..  As far as I understood you, the proper way to work with it is to handle response within **onSuccess()** method. Could you please check edited post?

Comment: yes, `getResponse()` doesn't return value now. Yes, to show data I use adapter and `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. ListView's content is updated on pull (pull-to-refresh list). But the funny thing is that on first pull nothing happens so `onFailure()` or `onSuccess` isn't invoked. But every next pull I'm getting an error from `onFailure()` method